# How send slider values using $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, slider

I have a simple form with two slider and two buttons created using links, because truthfully those links are images created with css.

So, I want to be able to send all slider values when you click the button and then retrieve those values in the second div to show it.

I want to do it using PHP, so I think the best way is to send over POST and then retrieve it using the same way.

```
</br></br></br>

<div class="main">
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="range" name="val1" id="val1" value="5" min="0" max="10" data-show-value="true"></br>
    <input type="range" name="val2" id="val2" value="5" min="0" max="10" data-show-value="true">
    </br>

</form>
</div>
<a class="btn1" href="#">Button 1 - View 1 (Sliders)</a></br>
<a class="btn2" href="#">Button 2 - View 2 (Results)</a>
<div class="second">
<p>--Second div---</p>

<p>--Value 1---</p>
<?php $_POST['val1'] ?>
<p>--Value 2---</p>
<?php $_POST['val2'] ?>
</div>
```

At first I want to know how to pass values between pages and then when you come back to the main view put the value selected before. I think this can be done using $_SESSION.

So, what do you suggest to get the values from the each slider and put it in the second div using PHP?
I want to develop a dynamic site when depends on the button that you click go to one page or another. I have nearly 20 possibilities depends on the button clicked, so I think that the best way is using divs and putting all the PHP and HTML code in a file and show or hide depends on the button that you click.

And I using bootstrap-slider library, but to do the example I used the jquery slider.

I've done a fiddle to see if someone is able to do it.
https://jsfiddle.net/dperezq/ph7mfu0v/

Comment: What's the problem? The values will be in `$_POST['val1']` and `$_POST['val2']`, just like any other form field.

Comment: I cannot see the response using `<?php echo ($_POST['val1']); ?>` in the second div

Comment: Using that I cannot see the values in the second div. I´ve updated the jsfiddle and I´ve tried many combinations to get it without result.

Comment: The code in the question is missing `echo`.

Comment: You can't see it in jsfiddle because it doesn't run PHP.

Comment: Your form doesn't have a submit button. How are you sending it to PHP?

Comment: Yes, I realised of that and now I´m running in Coda. I´ve tried using this `echo $_POST['val1'];` and I cannot see the values, however if I print `echo hi;` I can see it without problems

Comment: It won't be set until you submit the form and it reloads the page. If you want to update the page immediately without reloading, you need to do it in Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87414/discussion-between-ukandroid-and-barmar).